# write on ui label from different class in qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am using Qt in my project and facing some difficulty in accessing ui label from other class,I have mainwindow and Yar class as shown below.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "yar.h"
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
Yar b;


private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
void dispal();


private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QObject::connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),&b,SLOT(lll()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::dispal(){

ui->label->setText("hello");
}
```

Yar.h

```
#ifndef YAR_H
#define YAR_H

#include <QObject>


class Yar : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit Yar(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
void lll();

};

#endif // YAR_H


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{//ui->label->setText("hello");

  //b.wrrrot();
//dispal();
}
```

Yar.cpp

```
#include "yar.h"
#include <iostream>
Yar::Yar(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
//setupUi(this);

//QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(dis), &a, SLOT(dispal()));
//emit wrrrot();
}

void Yar::lll(){
//emit wrrrot();
std::cout<<"gfggdf"<<std::endl;
}
```

In my gui i have one push button and one label, I have connected push button with lll() function of class Yar and when I click push button it is displaying **gfggdf** in console but I want to display this text in ui label, could you please help me how can I display my data in ui label from function lll();

Comment: Why do you need to modify the label text through the `Yar` class, if you can do it directly?

Comment: becuase push button is like a initialization, when I click push button , function lll() will perform different call and display the result..thats why I need to modify label through Yar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to emit signal from Yar::lll() i.e.

```
emit updateLabelText("your text");
```

And connect this signal to the slot that handles GUI (changes label with given text) in the MainWindow.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have accepted your answer because I have tried this thing before reading your answer and it was working..